# Hide warnings: Simultaneous accesses to ... but modification requires exclusive access

Tags: swift, warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm using 3rd party libraries which are not yet ready for Swift 4, i.e. break the exclusive memory access rule ([SE-0176](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0176-enforce-exclusive-access-to-memory.md)).

So, my console is flooded with these warnings:

```
Simultaneous accesses to 0xb1ab1ab1a, but modification requires exclusive access.
Previous access (a modification) started at MyTarget`That3rdPartyLib.func(_:args:) + 123 (0xb1ab1ab1a).
Current access (a read) started at:
<callstack...>
```

How to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer when writing the question.

Project > Build Settings > Other Swift Flags > Debug > Add a flag: **-enforce-exclusivity=unchecked**

**Warning:** This is a temporary solution to clean up your console with Swift 3.2, while the 3rd party developers are getting ready for Swift 4. If you have warnings (even hidden) in Swift 3.2, your app is going to crash after transition to Swift 4.

Comment: My app not just flooded this message at console, but was crashing too.